# wrong result while defining node size based on node degree in networkx

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I know that similar question was asked before, but mine is a bit complicated. I am trying to define node sizes of the networkx graph based on their out degree, but getting some mess. here is my codes:

```
nodes = pd.read_csv('nodes_1984.csv')
edges = pd.read_csv('edges_1984.csv')
nodes.head()
```

[this how my data containing nodes looks like (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGjmW.png)

```
network=nx.DiGraph() 
for row in nodes.iterrows():
    network.add_node(row[1][0], Label=row[1][1], region=row[1][2], pos=(row[1][4], row[1][3]))
for row in edges.iterrows():
    network.add_edge(row[1][0],row[1][1], weight=row[1][3])

pos=nx.get_node_attributes(network,'pos')

d_out = network.out_degree()  #dictionary of {nodes:out_degree_values}
d_out_val = []  #creating a list which contains values of out_degree of nodes and sorting them in the same order as they were in the d_out dict

for w in sorted(d_out.keys()):
    d_out_val.append(d_out[w])

d_out_val

plt.figure(figsize=(32,28)) #plotting my network
nx.draw(network, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=[s * 100 for s in d_out_val], node_color="w")
plt.show()
```

result is that sizes of my nodes in the graph do not correspond to out degree values of these nodes though I sorted the list (d_out_val) containing degree values of the nodes accordingly above. 
Could you please tell what this issue can be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Pass `nx.draw` the `nodelist` argument in which you give a sorted list of nodes. So instead of

```
nx.draw(network, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=[s * 100 for s in d_out_val], node_color="w")
```

you'll have:

```
nx.draw(network, pos, nodelist=sorted(network.nodes()), with_labels=True, node_size=[s * 100 for s in d_out_val], node_color="w")
```

If you don't give the `nodelist` argument, networkx will use `network.nodes()` (which is not sorted unlike your `node_size` list).